# SWIFT use of INTs with SQL

Tags: swift, sqlite, int

Can I just pass this by everyone to check that I'm doing the write thing?
As we know with Swift you have to specify the type in Int you are using.
When I create an ID for an SQL Database along the lines of

```
(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)
```

The ID needs to map to a Var Int32(). Is that correct?

Comment: In what context? Are you using a SQLite library in your app? Core Data? Or are you trying to map your server database schema to an object hierarchy in your app? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Indeed SQLite, with FMDB.

Answer (score 2):

See SQLite's [`sqlite3_last_insert_rowid`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) (or FMDB's [`lastInsertRowId`](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabase.html#//api/name/lastInsertRowId)), which returns the value assigned to that integer primary key for the last inserted row. This function returns a `sqlite3_int64`.

For that reason, I always treat these `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` keys as 64-bit integers.

Comment: So according to that link my ID INTEGER is an alias to ROWID and will be Int64. For the App I'm working on would doubt if any of the tables ever had more than 100 rows. Will test and report back. Many thanks.

Comment: What I didn't explain is how this question arose. I'm using FMDB for the SQLite interface. FMDB has a call along along the lines of:

resultSet2.intForColumn("ID")

where the int is Int32. I have transposed all the record/row related into to Int32 and everything is working peachy. But I don't understand why if they're meant to be Int64.

Comment: @EdwardHasted - Since we know it's really a 64-bit value, I wouldn't use `intForColumn` for the ID, which returns it as `Int32`. I'd suggest `longForColumn`, which returns an `Int` type. (Or you could use `longLongIntForColumn`, which returns an `Int64`.)